# Python Flask Goes to sleep mode on AWS EC2

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my python flask application on AWS EC2 server and followed this tutorital

https://github.com/yeshwanthlm/YouTube/blob/main/flask-on-aws-ec2.md

But I have noticed that my application goes into sleep mode and I have to restart it with `sudo systemctl start helloworld`  command.

How to resolve this issue?